# Proof of a Symmetric-Like Expression

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, symmetric-polynomials

Consider $n$ is a positive integer number.
Let the set $I_k$, $1\leq k \leq n$, is defined by $I_k=\{1,2,\cdots ,n\}-\{k\}$.  Assume that the polynomial $h_k$ is defined by:
$$
h_k=\prod_{\substack { 1\leq t \leq n}} (a_k+b_t)\, 
\prod_{\substack { i,j\in I_k  \\ i<j}} (a_i-a_j).
$$
*My question:* How to proof the following relation:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\, (-1)^{k-1}\, h_k=(\prod_{\substack { 1\leq i,j \leq n  \\ i<j}} (a_i-a_j))\, (a_1+b_1+a_2+b_2+\cdots + a_n+b_n)\tag{1}
$$

*Example:*
Let $n=4$ then the polynomial $h_k$, $1\leq k \leq 4$, are given by: 
$$
\begin{array}{}
h_1= \left( a_{{1}}+b_{{1}} \right)  \left( a_{{1}}+b_{{2}} \right) 
 \left( a_{{1}}+b_{{3}} \right)  \left( a_{{1}}+b_{{4}} \right) 
 \left( a_{{2}}-a_{{3}} \right)  \left( a_{{2}}-a_{{4}} \right) 
 \left( a_{{3}}-a_{{4}} \right),\\
h_2=\left( a_{{2}}+b_{{1}} \right)  \left( a_{{2}}+b_{{2}} \right) 
 \left( a_{{2}}+b_{{3}} \right)  \left( a_{{2}}+b_{{4}} \right) 
 \left( a_{{1}}-a_{{3}} \right)  \left( a_{{1}}-a_{{4}} \right) 
 \left( a_{{3}}-a_{{4}} \right),\\
h_3=\left( a_{{3}}+b_{{1}} \right)  \left( a_{{3}}+b_{{2}} \right) 
 \left( a_{{3}}+b_{{3}} \right)  \left( a_{{3}}+b_{{4}} \right) 
 \left( a_{{1}}-a_{{2}} \right)  \left( a_{{1}}-a_{{4}} \right) 
 \left( a_{{2}}-a_{{4}} \right),\\
h_4=\left( a_{{4}}+b_{{1}} \right)  \left( a_{{4}}+b_{{2}} \right) 
 \left( a_{{4}}+b_{{3}} \right)  \left( a_{{4}}+b_{{4}} \right) 
 \left( a_{{1}}-a_{{2}} \right)  \left( a_{{1}}-a_{{3}} \right) 
 \left( a_{{2}}-a_{{3}} \right).
\end{array}
$$
Then we can check that the relation $(1)$ holds for $n=4$, as follows 
$$
\begin{array}{}
\sum_{k=1}^4\, (-1)^{k-1}\, h_k=\\
\left( a_{{1}}-a_{{2}} \right)  \left( a_{{1}}-a_{{3}} \right) 
 \left( a_{{1}}-a_{{4}} \right)  \left( a_{{2}}-a_{{3}} \right) 
 \left( a_{{2}}-a_{{4}} \right)  \left( a_{{3}}-a_{{4}} \right) 
 \left( a_{{1}}+b_{{1}}+\cdots +a_{{4}}+b_{{4}
} \right).
\end{array}
$$
*My try:* If $a_i=a_j$ for some $1\leq i , j \leq n$, $i\neq j$ then the 
$\operatorname{RHS}$ of $(1)$ is zero and also we can prove the $\operatorname{LHS}$ of $(1)$ is zero ($n-2$ of $h_k$'s are zero and the other two $h_k$ are equal). I dont know how to show that if $\sum_{i=1}^n(a_i+b_i)=0$ then $\operatorname{LHS}$ of $(1)$ is zero.

*Code:* The Maple code of this question is provided [here](https://ufile.io/4oyoz).

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here's a start.
I think you'll find that $h_i$ has degree $k$ in $a_i$ and $k-2$ in $a_j$ for $j \ne i$, and total degree $k(k-1)/2+1$ in $a_1,\ldots,a_k$.  Thus the left side of (1) has degree $k$ in each $a_j$ and total degree $k(k-1)/2+1$ in $a_1,\ldots,a_k$.   So does the right side.  The left side is $0$ when $a_i = a_j$ for some $i \ne j$, so it must be $\displaystyle\prod_{\substack { 1\leq i,j \leq n  \\ i<j}} (a_i-a_j)$ times a polynomial that has degree $1$ in each $a_i$ and total degree $1$ in $a_1, \ldots, a_k$.  Moreover, that polynomial is symmetric under permutations of the $a_i$, so it must be of the form
$A \sum_i a_i + B$, where $A$ and $B$ are polynomials in $b_1,\ldots, b_k$.

Comment: I appreciate you answering the question. Thanks

Comment: Professor Israel, I can't understand the reason of the existence of the  term $\sum_{i=1}^n(a_i+b_i)$ in $\operatorname{LHS}$ of $(1)$. Is it possible to ask you to explain more. In fact you mentioned that the $\operatorname{LHS}$ of $(1)$ 
"must be of the form
$A \sum_i a_i + B$, where $A$ and $B$ are polynomials in $b_1,\ldots, b_k$", but the $\operatorname{LHS}$ is in the form of $\displaystyle\prod_{\substack { 1\leq i,j \leq n  \\ i<j}} (a_i-a_j)\sum_i a_i+\displaystyle\prod_{\substack { 1\leq i,j \leq n  \\ i<j}} (a_i-a_j) \sum_i b_i$.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry.  The last "it" does not refer to the left side of (1), but rather to that divided by $\displaystyle\prod_{\substack { 1\leq i,j \leq n  \\ i<j}} (a_i-a_j)$.